# Print result if statement to exec is an expression

Tags: python, exec

In python, if I `exec` a statement which prints a value, I will see the output, e.g., `exec("print 10")` gives me output 10. However, if I do `exec("10")` I got nothing as output, where as if I type 10 in the interactive shell I got 10 as output. How do I get this output when using `exec`? That is if the statement to be executed is an expression, I print its result.

My question is how I can decide whether the statement to execute is an expression. Am I supposed to do the following:

```
def my_exec(script):
  try:
    print eval(compile(script, '<string>', 'eval'))
  except SyntaxError:
    exec(script)

# Prints 10.
my_exec("print(10)")

# Prints 10 as well.
my_exec("10")
```

UPDATE:

Basically I want the behavior of executing a cell in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please do not ask, immediately delete, and repost a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683687/print-result-if-statement-to-exec-is-an-expression).

Comment: Thank you @TigerhawkT3! However this is not a duplicate. There isn't an answer in the post you mentioned.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Would you remove the duplication mark?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, executing 10 doesn't make sense in real life. How can you execute a number? But, you can execute a command like `exec("print(10)")`. I don't see the need of creating a `my_exec` function. It behaves the same as the normal `exec`. In the interactive shell, everything works differently, so don't try to compare. Basically, `exec("print(10)")` is the command you are looking for. Another way not using exec is `print(10)`.

Comment: Thank you! I totally understand that.

Comment: For example, the `compile(..., "<string>", "single")` has the behavior of my `my_exec`, but it does not support statements with multiple code blocks which are all executable.

Comment: Then, it is possible to use compile instead of my_exec. That was my point.  Why go through the hassle when you can use a built in function?

Comment: it executes up to the end of the first executable block. for example, `exec(compile("print 42\n print 10", "", "single"))` prints 42 only. my `my_exec` works but it has two compile involved. what i am asking here is indeed a more principled way like you mentioned.